# How do I set the layout to the previous layout when the back button is pressed?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have the following code to handle button presses in my app:

```
if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && CURRENT_VIEW == MAIN_MENU_ACTIVE) {
        Window window = this.getWindow();

        window.setContentView(R.layout.main);
        CURRENT_VIEW = MAIN_MENU_ACTIVE;

        return true;

    }
```

When it's run though, android just jumps straight to the return statement, instead of changing the layout. Is there anything that I am doing wrong here? This is for a game, so essentially I want the user to be able to navigate from the game creation screen back to the main menu by hitting the back button.

Comment: What type of fields are CURRENT_VIEW and MAIN_MENU_ACTIVE? Your problem must be right at CURRENT_VIEW == MAIN_MENU_ACTIVE.

Comment: Those are both integers. I'm using them to track which layout is shown on screen. If I put a breakpoint at the if statement, it just jumps straight to the return statement.

Comment: OMG my bad, accidentally made the if statement not go through. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

just use `setContentView(R.layout.main);`. Don't start using a `Window`, as i'm fairly sure you don't need to.

Comment: I started using window because it didn't work when I tried it with the activity. It always just skipped to the return statement. It's like I have a bad if statement or something.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `setContentView` multiple times. Why not simply use `finish()`, which would return the user to the previous activity?

Comment: Why can't I call setContentView multiple times? I've got 3 places in my code that use setContentView, and they all work fine.

Comment: You're calling it multiple times successively? This tends to produce errors. I'm not sure that it's specifically disallowed though.

Comment: Yeah, this is for a game, so essentially I want the user to be able to navigate from the game creation screen back to the main menu by hitting the back button. I could restart the activity, but then I would have to re-load everything that's loaded on launch.